# swapping function

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, swap

right now i have a function that would swap places from a list its index with the next number for example `swap_cards([1,2,3,4,5], 2)` -> `swap_cards = [1,2,4,3,5]`
how do i change my code so when i call it in another function i can change the index of the function swap_cards

```
def swap_cards(cards, index):
    cards_len = len(cards)
    if not 0 <= index < cards_len:
        return cards
    elif index == cards_len - 1:
        return [cards[-1]] + cards[1:-1] + [cards[0]]
    else:
        return cards[:index] + [cards[index+1]] + [cards[index]] +\
            cards[index+2:]

def move_3(cards):
    if 3 in cards:
        swap_cards(cards, cards.index(3))
        return cards
```

for now i can only find where the index is but not sure how to move the index one more space

Comment: What do you mean by "change my code so when i call it in another function i can change the index of the function swap_cards"?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean when you say you want to change indices.

```
def swap_cards(cards, index):
    cards_len = len(cards)
    if not 0 <= index < cards_len:
        return cards
    elif index == cards_len - 1:
        return [cards[-1]] + cards[1:-1] + [cards[0]]
    else:
        return cards[:index] + [cards[index+1]] + [cards[index]] +\
            cards[index+2:]
```

Updated function.

```
def move_3(cards):
    for item in cards:
        if item == 3:
           return swap_cards(cards, index=3)
```

If you type the same numbers list [1,2,3,4,5] in to this function you will get [1, 2, 3, 5, 4].

```
print(move_3([1,2,3,4,5]))
[1, 2, 3, 5, 4]
```